# Wolverine in both Pacific and European theaters?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, the-wolverine, x-men-origins-wolverine

If you watch *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* and then watch *The Wolverine*, you can find an incongruency in Wolverine's story. In *X-Men Origins*, you can see that in the World War II scene, Wolverine and Victor fight in Normandy. In *The Wolverine*, he is a prisoner of war in Japan. What happened? Both movies were made **before** *Days of Future Past*.

Comment: _"If you watch X-Men Origins: Wolverine and then watch The Wolverine, you can find an incongruency in Wolverine's story."_ No, you find *several* incongruencies, and wonder why at least one of these two ever got made :-)

Comment: True. But I am wondering how this big one slipped through. The war was over in Japan before more troops got shipped over from Germany. How could they mess that up?

Comment: Wolverine being multiple places at once is often joked to be one of his powers, even (especially) in comics.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there's no incongruency.

The Normandy landings happened in June 1944, the atomic bombings in August 1945. Unless I'm forgetting *The Wolverine* stating Logan was a prisoner for a very long time, it's not unreasonable to think he could have been in both theaters.

It's certainly not explicitely explained, but time-wise, it's not physically impossible.

Comment: But based on the technology of the time, moving troops from Germany to Japan would take too long. The war ended before all the logistics were worked out. Also, for Wolverine to become a POW in Japan, he must be in combat in Japan.

Comment: @Neo1009 Moving troops in mass may have been difficult but given the skills that he likely had shown they could have sent him individually to the pacific theater which would have been a lot easier.

Comment: are we sure that both scenes are from only WWII? could it be one in WWI? he was a prisoner a long time as shown in the movie